# HAPI FHIR R4 : Modifiers on ReferenceParam

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm currently building a FHIR (R4) Server, and i try to implement the following request:

```
[base]/PractitionerRole?practitioner.active:not=true
```

I know that active is a Token Param, and thanks to HAPI, i can use the following command :

```
TokenParam tokenSubject = referenceParam.toTokenParam(myContext);
```

But sadly, all the modifier part is lost : in my referenceParam, i only have a chain part (active:not), and a value part (true), so i don't have any modifiers, missing, etc..
So when i convert it to a TokenParam, i don't have neither the modifiers, missing, etc ...

**So here is my question** : Is there a way to have a ReferenceParam that has modifiers?
I would like to have a chain part (active), a modifier (not) and a value (true), as in a real TokenParam

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct. My best guess is you're using token search directly, instead of as part of a chain.

[Token/Identifier](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/server_plain/rest_operations_search.html#search-parameters-tokenidentifier) alone would be appropriate if you were searching for `active` directly on `PractionerRole`.

For example: http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/PractitionerRole?active:not=true

However, you're doing a nested search with `?practitioner.active:not=true`

Try [Search Parameters > 4.5.9 Chained Resource References > Dynamic Chains](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/server_plain/rest_operations_search.html#chained-resource-references)

For example: http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/PractitionerRole?practitioner.active:not=true

NB: `active:not=true` will return both `active:missing` and `active=false`